# C: not printing what I want

Tags: c, printf

I have a simple code to print only the numbers in a string, but yet it's not printing what I want and I have absolutely no idea why. It should print 1 and 10 but it prints 1, 10 and 100. Now why the 100?? :s

```
char string[50] = "1 10 +";
int value = 0;

for (int i = 0; i != strlen(string); i++)
{
    if (isdigit(string[i])){
            value = value*10 + atoi(&string[i]);
            printf(" %d\n", value);
    }
    else
    {
        if (string[i] == ' ')
        {
                value = 0;
        }
    }
}
return(0);
}
```

Comment: `atoi` converts the entire *string* you point it to to a number. You seem to assume it works only on the first character. Now do the maths...

Comment: If you want to convert a character to an integer, just subtract 48 (ASCII '0'): `(int) (string[i] - '0')`

Comment: Oh sorry that should be value

Comment: Ok thanks it works now :) I also had to put printf in if string[0] == ' ' part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the function isdigit() performs correctly, the string[i] inside the if block would be in the range between '0'..'9'.

Replace your line:

```
value = value*10 + atoi(&string[i]);
```

with

```
value = value*10 + string[i] - '0'; // the difference between string[i] and '0' 
                                    // are the integer value you're looking for.
                                    // i.e.  '9' - '0' equals to 9.
```

Further, you probably don't want to print the value inside the loop. Instead, print the final value  at the end might be better.

Answer (score -3):

Here is a solution that will print only the digits of a given string separated by a single white space.

```
int main(void) {
        char *string = "1   10  +";
        int len = strlen(string);
        for( int i = 0 ; i < len ; ) {
                while (i < len && isdigit(string[i])) printf("%c", string[i++]);
                while (i < len && ! isdigit(string[i])) i++;
                printf(" ");
        }
        return 0;
}
```